# How to iterate a given process 1'000 times and average the results

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, iteration

I am here to ask you about R language and how to construct a loop to iterate some functions several times.

Here is my problem: I have a numeric matrix obtained from previous analyses (`matrix1`) that I want to compare (using the `overlap` function that results in a single value) with another numeric matrix that I get by extracting values of a given raster with a set of randomly created points, as many as the values in the first numeric matrix.
I want to repeat the random sampling procedure 1'000 times, in order to get 1'000 different sets of random points, then repeat the comparison with `matrix1` 1'000 times (one for each set of random points), and, in the end, calculate the mean of the results to get a single value.

Hereafter I give you an example of the functions I want to use:

```
#matrix1 is the first matrix, obtained before starting the potential loop;
#LineVector is a polyline shapefile that has to be used within the loop and downloaded before it;
#Raster is a raster from which I should extract values at points location;

#The loop should start from here:
Random_points <- st_sample(LineVector, size =  2000, exact = TRUE, type = "random")

Random_points <- Random_points[!st_is_empty(Random_points)]

Random_points_vect <- vect(Random_points)

Random_values <- terra::extract(Raster, Random_points_vect, ID = F, raw = T)

Random_values <- na.omit(Random_values[, c("Capriolo")]) 

Values_list <- list(matrix1, Random_values)

Overlapping_value <- overlap(Values_list, type = "2")

#This value, obtained 1'000 times, has then to be averaged into a single number.
```

I hope I have posed my question in a clear and understandable manner, and I hope you can help me with this problem.

Thanks to everyone in advance, I wish you a good day!

Comment: In the last line, variable `lista` is not defined. Did you mean `values_list`?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the typo error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy way i can figure out is to use "replicate":

```
values <- replicate(1000, {
  Random_points <- st_sample(LineVector, size =  2000, exact = TRUE, type = "random")
  Random_points <- Random_points[!st_is_empty(Random_points)]
  Random_points_vect <- vect(Random_points)
  Random_values <- terra::extract(Raster, Random_points_vect, ID = F, raw = T)
  Random_values <- na.omit(Random_values[, c("Capriolo")]) 
  Values_list <- list(matrix1, Random_values)
  Overlapping_value <- overlap(Values_list, type = "2")
  Overlapping_value
})

mean(values)
```

Comment: library `future.apply` has the function `future_replicate` that allows you to do the calculations in paralell (multiprocessing)

Comment: Thank you so much, that's exactly what I was looking for! I am not so expert of pure R language, so many thanks! :)